# Resolution is high, but looks zoomed on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, display, resolution, gnome

I reformatted this Ubuntu Gnome machine that went from 13.10 up to a 15.10 beta over the last few years, after fiddling with the beta, it wasn't able to boot or be repaired. I installed a fresh install of Ubuntu's LTS 14.04 for a more stable setup, with a newly formatted / partition and keeping only /home, /srv and /opt partitions.

The installer's resolution was 1680x1080 but everything was huge. I expected this to be fixed when I finally reboot and probably change drivers.

I used both Nouveau drivers and Nvidia's and it was still the same, tried changing Gnome's scaling factor only resizes the text, all other UI elements stay huge.

[image: changing Gnome's scaling]

Clicked on Activities:

[image: Activities Clicked]

Clicked on Show Applications:

[image: Show Applications]

Show Applications has tiny icons and truncated titles.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems like my trials of text-scaling-factor were close, but not the solution.

I was able to solve my issue using:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 1
```

It was set to a factor of 2 from the installer!